# Android Emulator clicking more than one item in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-emulator, padding

I have a grid view which is full of values for a word search,
Basically, I don't know why, but when I click a letter, it highlights the next 4 beneath.

[image: Wordsearch]

At first i thought it was because my vetical spacing was -40dip, howeverchanging this to 0, makes the spacing huge, this in turn fixes the problem, because the words are spaced so far apart that the long thin click highlighter in the image doesn't matter...

So what I'm really asking is, how can I reduce the click radius  It's fine to the left and the right, it's just the bottom .

Could it be padding?

This is the code for the gridview, and the linear layout above

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ScrollViewlLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="278dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

           <GridView
            android:id="@+id/WordSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="194dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.13"
            android:padding="2dip"
            android:paddingLeft="20dip"
            android:verticalSpacing="-50dip" >
        </GridView>
```

Comment: please reduce grid item height in getview method and check.

Comment: I don't have a gridview , but I solved it now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the style applied to the text views in the grid view.